# Как понять, что шрифт отрендерился

Tags: javascript

Как понять, что загруженный шрифт отрендерился? Не загрузился, а именно отрендерился.

У меня такая проблема — пока шрифт не отрендерился — элементы становятся очень широкими в Сафари, а я стараюсь в зависимости от ширины этих элементов скрывать ненужны.

Что-то типа http://352media.github.io/flexMenu/

Можно, конечно, поставить setTimeout, но это не железобетонное решение, отрендерится шрифт может и после таймаута.